# SQL: How to insert one row into tableA per each existing element on tableB with corresponding foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm updating my project's database. It already contains some users with data. I'm now creating a new table Book, and book has a foreign key pointing to table User, id_user. I want each User to get a default Book upon updating the database. Here's the new table Book and the old table User:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Book (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,    
    title VARCHAR(300),            
    id_user INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES User(id),
    UNIQUE (id)
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    UNIQUE (id)
);
```

So basically I want to select all Users, and per each User retrieved, insert an entry into table Book with the book.id_user field pointing to user.id and book.title = "default".

I can think of several ways to do this using a combination of PHP and SQL, but I think it would be cleaner to use just SQL. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Don't describe the code, post the code.

Comment: Added the table's code.

Comment: you have the books and users in a 1:1  relationship - you might want to consider if that is the correct design.

Comment: When you create tables they way you have them shown, you have duped up the index count by accident

Comment: @JamesSnell, the initial load requested in 1:1, but the schema itself is definitely 1:N...

Comment: @Drew, can you explain what will cause the index duplication? How can I avoid it?

Comment: yeah just ditch the `UNIQUE (id)` from the end. Run the results thru `show indexes from mytable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Book (title, id_user) SELECT 'default', id FROM User;
```

This selects each row from `User` and for each row inserts a default `title` and the `User.id` into `Book`.